Can I use my water heater as substitute for failed home heat boiler?
The boiler providing heat is not functional. My home uses a 4 zone radiant baseboard heating system with Solenoids controlling the flow of an H2O blend liquid to the 4 zones. The PEX, fittings, and electrical systems appear to be OK. Can I use a new propane 40 gal. water heater with large in yard tank of gas in place of the boiler? We live at 9250 ft. elevation.

What is the size of the boiler?  The size difference will tell how often the hot water tank will need to be on.  Boilers/hot water tanks works on the same principles.   If a H20 blend(or just plain water used for heat), then it needs to be isolated/separated from your drinking/washing water, so you need two hot water systems that do not mix.

Why the boiler is not functional might give better answers.  Unless the boiler itself is leaking, it should be possible to fix it.

What was the operating temperature of the circulating hot water to the baseboards before the boiler failed? Is the 40 gal water heater capable of heating water to that temperature? If not, the baseboard units will radiate or convect inadequate heat. Taken from a baseboard BTU chart online, reducing temp from 180F to 140F reduces BTU output to 55%.

Interesting. The boiler is failing just about the time that R290 mono bloc cold-climate heat pumps burst onto the scene.  It's almost like someone is giving you an opportunity!   Monoblocs keep the freon loop entirely inside the outdoor unit (highly efficient but flammable R290=propane).  It's hydronic - it interchanges coolant instead of freon, so no freon license needed. And R290 can get the water hot enough to work well in hydronic systems.   And yes, they do reverse as A/Cs but you'll need different indoor heads to catch condensate. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z_VDejZ_d58

No.
Some water heaters have provision to circulate room heating water through the tank in a secondary coil.
As a permanent solution, a 40 gallon hot water heater will not have the power to heat a home and also continue providing hot water, unless the home is very small; but yours has four zones so it can't be tiny
As a temporary solution, replumbing your heating system to the hot water heater and then back again when you fix the boiler would be a large and unnecessary cost.
The nail in the coffin is probably the "blend".  I don't know what that is but if it's anything you wouldn't want to drink, you also wouldn't want to circulate it through a coil in your hot water heater.
Perhaps you could entirely repurpose your hot water heater for home heating, through the primary tank!  But that would be strange, unchartered territory and for the cost of doing it, who knows if you could fix your boiler. This is very speculative.  More of an "if you were stranded in the woods, with gas, who knows Maybe this would work" idea.

i disagree on  replumbing your heating system to the hot water heater and then back again when you fix the boiler would be a large and unnecessary cost..   It would be if you don't have the tools, material, capability, and knowledge.  Otherwise it could be very easy - u really don't know unless u've seen what's what

If OP had the tools, material, and skills to do this he would not be asking if it was possible, and he would probably just fix his boiler.

TBH even if you put potable water into a new (rinsed) heating system, you wouldn't want to drink what came out, or anything that had been contaminated with it, even though the sludge is mostly rust

@ChrisH I agree.  I shall continue to not use this feature of my water heater. :)

@jay613 here (UK) we commonly have a couple of different methods using the same gas-fired boiler for both, with no mixing between heating and hot water.  The question therefore sounds rather strange at first

There are ways to do it, but they require an extra pump + heat exchanger (look up a Taco X-Block)

"Wow" re the Taco X-Block.  I'm sure it has its uses but for the price, which also requires a pump, some plumbing, and specialized knowledge, the uses must be very specialized.  I think @ChrisH is right, in the UK it was (maybe still is?) quite common to have radiator water circulated through a coil in a passive hot water storage tank.   A leak in the coil could pass sludgy water into the tank.  However, most UK homes also have a cold storage tank and everyone knows to drink only from taps fed directly from the supply, sometimes only the kitchen cold faucet.

Yes.
if you know what you are doing.  You'll find such [compact] systems available in apartments - for example in a closet in a ~500 sqft unit that is a combo gas fired domestic water heater + secondary hydronic loop to a combo heat+AC fan unit.  I just worked on one.  Whether a 40 gal hwr is btu sufficient for your heat is the question - u said home [house] with 4 zones probably not, compare the hwh BTU to the boiler BTU; it may work given the high mass 40 gallon hwh versus what might be a low mass boiler.  so yes you "can" use it, will u get adequate heat performance...FAFO.  Will it be better than a completely busted and non-repairable boiler which u can't get replaced right now as winter starts, probably.  And recognizing the difference between domestic [potable] hot water and your closed loop hydronic system.
